# Azure Application Insights Connection String

Tags: javascript, azure-application-insights, content-security-policy

My App Insights connection string contains two URLs: IngestionEndpoint and LiveEndpoint and they are different. Given that I'm adding the connection string to the website, I need to adjust my CSP connect-src to be able to connect to these URLs. By looking at the network, it seems it's only connecting to the IngestionEndpoint - will it ever need to connect to the other one? Or can I leave it off?

Comment: Check if  that your application is only connecting to the IngestionEndpoint and not the LiveEndpoint, in this case, I guess you can leave the LiveEndpoint from your CSP

Answer (score 1):

as i know, `IngestionEndpoint` is for collecting data (console logs, exceptions, dependency calls...) while `LiveEndpoint` is for collecting live metrics, which is enabled on-demand only when you visit Live Metrics section on Application Insights on Azure portal. You may try opening it on portal and see if your browser opening your website is making call to `LiveEndpoint`

Comment: I assume that has to be the right answer, however, I couldn’t see any attempts to connect to live URL when I launched the live view in Azure Portal. Maybe it’s not meant to work for the SPA apps or maybe some extra configuration required on the client side.

Comment: @andkorsh can you check if you set `.setSendLiveMetrics(true)`